# Debugging Ember.js errors: Error while loading route

Tags: ember.js

While in any particular case there are hints and clues on how to debug an error you get, I haven't really found a general Ember strategy.
For example, a typeError while loading a route:
`Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.router.lander')` (ignore the fact that I'm trying to access window.router.lander. It's irrelevant)

Why does Ember not tell you which route it's loading when this error happens? Or whether it happens in afterModel(), or activate()? And what's the general strategy for finding that sort of context info?

So far all I've got is adding a bunch of console.logs scattered around. For example with the error above:
1) Find all occurrences of window.router.lander in my code
2) before the first occurrence, add a console.log('is it the first occurrence?'), and after the first occurrence put a console.log('its not the first occurrence')
3) Do the same for every occurrence
4) refresh. One of the 'is it the nth occurrence?' won't have a closer, and now you know where the error happened.

Answer (score 2):

For better debugging, you can enable transitions logging by create app with `LOG_TRANSITIONS` and/or `LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL` properties:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  // Basic logging, e.g. "Transitioned into 'post'"
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true, 

  // Extremely detailed logging, highlighting every internal
  // step made while transitioning into a route, including
  // `beforeModel`, `model`, and `afterModel` hooks, and
  // information about redirects and aborted transitions
  LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true
});
```

Referenece: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/

Also, you can use canary build which provide detailed error stack:
http://emberjs.com/builds/#/canary

Answer (score 1):

Ember isn't particularly helpful when it comes to errors in the model hook, or the promises it returns. I'm sure I've read in one of the issues (or http://discuss.emberjs.com/ I'm not sure)  that this is an open issue in which they're working.

What I do is use the Chrome Developer Tools to debug the issue (instead of just console loggin it). From my experience it's usually:

1. you're not returning anything in the model hook
2. an error inside one of the `then` functions on the promise the model hook returns

I hope it helps you!

Comment: So I finished tracking down this issue, and it was actually in the `activate` hook--exactly what I'm talking about! No way to know what hook it's happening. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Could you post the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: I'm not looking for help with this particular issue - I've actually solved it now. I could put together a fiddle with 'a bug' and we could talk about the best way to find it?

Comment: Yes! I'd like to see the problem. PS: it's still a good idea to use the debugger, right?